# I need to import function from another file

Tags: python, function, file, import, python-import

I know how to import functions from normal files...
but my file name is ***'selection sort'***
it contains a space in between
is there a way to import function from these without renaming it

I tried `import selection sort` and `import selection_sort`… both didn't work

I also watched few videos and questions like these but can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `__import__()` function like:

```
selection_sort = __import__("selection sort")
```

and then the file `selection sort` is imported as `selection_sort`.

Comment: I mean it's like renaming only.... isn't there another way... just asking(curious)

Answer (score 0):

While it is not recommended to have a space in the file name, you could try:

```
selection_sort = __import__("selection sort")
```